# only number for textbox in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i want one textbox which only accpet the number, this solution i need without html5 support.

i have textbox inside the custom directive template.

```
ng-keypress="Validation($event)"
```

and

in controller of that directive, i wrote like this :

```
 $scope.Validation = function (e) {
                    //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
                    if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
```

but it is not working, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the following line before the `return false;`:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

This will prevent the keypress event propagation and will cancel the user's input.